# Run Azure Pipelines task only once per PR

Tags: azure-pipelines

In my Azure Pipeline builds, I'd like to add a Github comment only once per PR:

```
- task: GitHubComment@0
  condition: <what to put here?>
  inputs:
    gitHubConnection: "MyConnection"
    repositoryName: "$(Build.Repository.Name)"
    comment: "PR available for testing on https://example.com/?=$(dockertag)"
```

I have thought of creating a Variable group "branches-with-successful-builds", and use the Azure CLI to write variables in there in each successful build.

Would there be an easier way?

Comment: Hi Alfonso; is there any special reason not to put this task in your build pipeline? You say you want it to be run "once per successful build", and that's exactly what it would do.

Comment: Hi Vince, sorry long day, I meant "run only once per Github PR". I was hoping to find a predefined variable that I can use, that would indicate how many builds have been successfully run for that PR trigger. 

At this point I am thinking on ditching this `GithubComment` task and use the Github API directly to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, by configuring two things:

1. putting the task in a separate pipeline
2. configuring a [GitHub Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) to run that pipeline whenever a pull request is opened

Answer (score 0):

Use custom condition:

```
eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
```

Here is the reference doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages#run-if-the-build-is-run-by-a-branch-policy-for-a-pull-request-if-failing

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Sure, add the reference doc link.